# Failed building wheel for bcrypt when running pip install flask-bcrypt

Tags: python, bcrypt

I'm trying to run pip install flask-bcrypt for my flask application but i'm running into the following error
=============================DEBUG
ASSISTANCE=============================
If you are seeing a compilation error, please try the following steps to
successfully install bcrypt:
1) Upgrade to the latest pip and try again. This will fix errors for most
users. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip
2) Ensure you have a recent Rust toolchain installed. bcrypt requires
rustc >= 1.56.0.

```
      Python: 3.9.12
      platform: Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0
      pip: n/a
      setuptools: 65.5.0
      setuptools_rust: 1.5.2
      rustc: 1.64.0 (a55dd71d5 2022-09-19)
      =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE============================

  error: `cargo rustc --lib --message-format=json-render-diagnostics --manifest-path src\_bcrypt\Cargo.toml --release -v --features 'pyo3/abi3-py36 pyo3/extension-module' -- --crate-type cdylib` failed with code 101
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for bcrypt
Failed to build bcrypt
ERROR: Could not build wheels for bcrypt, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I have already tried upgrading to the latest pip, pip install wheel, and updating rustc. Sorry for the confusion, first time asking for help on stackoverflow.

Comment: error: `cargo rustc --lib --message-format=json-render-diagnostics --manifest-path src\_bcrypt\Cargo.toml --release -v --features 'pyo3/abi3-py36 pyo3/extension-module' -- --crate-type cdylib` failed with code 101

Comment: ERROR: Could not build wheels for bcrypt, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: Welcome to SO. ([Ask] and the [tour] are good starting points.) Please [edit] your question to include the full error output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by a lack of package management. I swapped from windows to ubuntu and created a virtual environment and the problem was resolved.